# Problems with simple example on WebSharper's official site

Tags: f#, websharper

I have downloaded and installed the latest version of WebSharper.  On [this page](http://websharper.com/docs/getting-started) there is an example, in which one of the lines is as follows:

```
let HomePage =
    Template "HomePage" <| fun ctx ->
        [ Div [Text "HOME"] Links ctx Div [new Controls.HelloControl()] ]
```

In Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate RC, the "Web Application (Sitelet)" template already provides the following code:

```
let HomePage =
    Skin.WithTemplate "HomePage" <| fun ctx ->
        [
            Div [Text "HOME"]
            Links ctx
        ]
```

When I try to add `Div [new Controls.HelloControl ()]` after `Links ctx` Visual Studio redlines `Links ctx` with the message:  `This value is not a function and cannot be applied.`  I have tried changing `Skin.WithTemplate` to just `Template`, but then `Template` itself gets redlined with the message `The value or constructor Template is not defined`.

Any help in resolving the problem will be greatly appreciated.  It would also be helpful to know if the official documentation at the WebSharper web site is generally up-to-date.

Here is a screen shot.

[image: Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let HomePage =
    Skin.WithTemplate "HomePage" <| fun ctx ->
        [
            Div [Text "HOME"]
            Links ctx
            Div  [new Controls.HelloControl ()]
        ]
```

Notice the line break. F# has a whitespace-significant syntax.

Comment: Awesome!  Although, I should mention that the code as written on the web site itself does not compile--at least not in my installation of Visual Studio.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Shredderroy I've just started learning Websharper and also found several mistakes on the first sample that stop it from working.

Comment: @JonHarrop The WebSharper team is friendly. Contact them and they'd gladly assist you with anything. If you find mistakes and report them, they'll do their best to fix them quickly.